# Motherboard bios is randomly resetting bios settings after reboots?

Tags: motherboard, bios, troubleshooting

have a PC with multiple issues and idk where to start debugging, the components are expensive and difficult to replace (because of the water-cooling system, even replacing the GPU is non-trivial), any help appreciated,

symptoms:

- bios is randomly resetting all its settings during reboot, and then give the explicit message "BIOS settings have been reset, press any
  key to blah blah blah" - this doesn't happen every time, maybe 50%-ish? (it's not *exactly* 50% either)
- Speccy cannot see what CPU it is, just saying it's "AMD K19" 32 times (equal to number of threads, 16 Cores 32 threds), but speccy is acting like it's 32 physical 1-core CPUs in 1 motherboard (like how some server motherboards have 4 physical CPUs in 1 motherboard). Speccy cannot see the CPU temperature either.
- all the 4x ram have RGB, but sometimes 1 of the ramsticks is black until reboot
- The ram RGB is having seizures/rapid-flickering during boot.

hardware:

- Motherboard: X570 Aorus Master
- CPU:  AMD Ryzen 9 5950x (16 cores, 32 threads), watercooled
- GPU: 2x GTX1070Ti in SLI, Asus Strix, watercooled
- PSU: Corsair AX1600i (1600W 80+ Titanium)
- RAM: 32GB total, 4x8GB G.Skill TridentZ RGB, DDR4, 3200 MHz / PC4-25600, CL14, 1.35V, unbuffered ( https://cdon.no/elektronikk/g-skill-tridentz-rgb-series-ddr4-sett-16-gb-2-x-8-gb-dimm-288-pin-3200-mhz-pc4-25600-cl14-1-35-v-ikke-bufret-ikke-ecc-p50085108 )
- OS: Windows 10 x64

Comment: sounds like the cmos battery might by dying.

Comment: "Clear CMOS Jumper" set  or dirt which shortens it ?

Comment: Speccy's most recent version is dated 21 May 2018 so ofcourse its going to struggle with your setup. Use more recent software, something like cpu-z will detect your cpu fine. A bios reset can happen for several reasons, like mentioned already it could be the cmos battery. However, many motherboards will revert to default settings after it spontaneous reboots or boot errors. This allows overclockers to push the system without getting locked out and having to reset manually. Reseat (remove and place back) your RAM to see if that helps with the RGB lighting.